# Script terminates for no apparent reason

Tags: php

I'm struggling with a script that imports data via XML. There are a total of about 19,000 products, spread out over 76 files and my scripts runs through each file, parses the data and imports it into the database.

For some reason however, the script terminates without telling me whats wrong.

1. I'm using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` with `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`
2. I have error reporting on the SQL, but there are no errors
3. I'm tracking the memory usage via `memory_get_usage()` - Doesnt come near the set `memory_limit`
4. I reset the `time_limit()` for each project and there is plenty of time

The weird thing is that the script stops at different points, based on the amount of logging that I output. If I don't change the output, the script stops at the same point. If I add (or remove) extra logging (/output) the script stops at different points.

It seems like it has something to do with memory or a timeout, because of termination at random points based on output, but I can't figure out what's causing it. There are no errors messages...

What can I do to find out what's wrong?

**Update**

It seems errors are not showing on the server after all. I just forced a fatal error (removed a semi-colon) and then I got a browser message saying there was a 500 server error. When I do the same on my local machine I get a real error message. What could this be? When i print `error_reporting()` I get "1" and `ini_get("display_errors")` shows me "6143" (which is E_ALL). How can I get the error message to show?

I've also checked `phpinfo()` for the time limit, by default it is 30 but when I add `set_time_limit(60);` before `phpinfo`, it shows 60. So that all seems right. According to the phpinfo `safe_mode` is off

After timing the script execution I saw that it died after 12 seconds - So it can't be the time_limit

Comment: Are you sure your `error_reporting` and/or `display_errors` settings are not overridden somewhere?

Comment: `display_errors` only set via `php.ini`

Comment: @Amir it can be set with `ini_set`

Comment: @JordanDoyle, Yes, but if it contains Fatal error, it does not display it

Comment: Updated my question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error was caused by an infinite loop (fatal error) and because error_reporting is switched off in php.ini the fatal errors didn't show (like @amir said). I managed to reproduce the issue on my local machine and did get the error that lead me to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Perhaps your script is in safe mode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php